# Why have I been banned from suggesting edits to posts?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, suggested-edit-bans

The title pretty much says it all, but I will provide a bit more information.

Last night I realized there was a user who was tagging multiple multivariable calculus questions as [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis), and so I started editing these posts to remove that tag. (I felt it was false advertising, so to speak.)

However, later I became aware that I was banned from suggesting edits. Can someone please explain to me why this occurred?

On top of that, I noticed some my edits that were rejected and then edited for the same thing that I suggested.

Comment: The short version is that too many of your edit suggestions were rejected, and therefore the system imposed an automatic temporary suggested-edit ban.

Comment: An alternative, and perhaps more constructive, approach to editing out the tags would be making a suggestion in a comment that the questioner him- or herself remove them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was something automatically done because a large percentage of your recent suggested edits were rejected. By my count 9 of the 15 edits you have suggested in the last 24 hours have been rejected. That's a 60% failure rate! The actual formula looks at the previous seven days. If, during this period, $$3 \cdot \text{rejects} - 15 \geq \text{approvals}$$ you will be banned from suggesting edits for one week. ([Source 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337) and [Source 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192).)

Take this time to [review your suggested edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and try to determine what you can do to improve them. (Speaking personally, a suggested edit that only removes a *questionable* (not outright *incorrect*) tag will probably be rejected. Try to make your suggestions more substantive, as at least two users will be taking the time to review them.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree by and large with what you have said. I would like to add and this is probably where we will disagree that inappropriate tagging should be edited. The fact that this specific user had 43 real analysis tag after the last of my edits were accepted and now has 32 says a lot.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias Yes, inappropriate tags should be edited. Step 1 toward editing them: earn 2000 reputation.